# Type mismatch when checking the value of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code hitting

> error 13 :Type Mismatch

whenever I enter or change the value in C59, C59 contains this formula `=ROUNDUP(D59/C57,0)`. I am guessing its because of the different variable but do not know how to solve it, any kind assistance is greatly appreciated!

```
If Range("C59").Value = "0" Then
        Sheets("InvPL").Rows("78:79").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
        Sheets("InvPL").Rows("78:79").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to make sure `C57` is not `0` as you are dividing by it, in which case `C59` will be `#DIV/0!` (an error)

You cannot check the `.Value` property of a cell if it contains an error.

Check cell `C59` for the error first:

```
If IsError(Worksheets("InvPL").Range("C59")) Then
  Msgbox "C59 contains an error. If C57=0 then it is a divide by zero error."
Else
  If Range("C59").Value = "0" Then
    Sheets("InvPL").Rows("78:79").EntireRow.Hidden = True
  Else
    Sheets("InvPL").Rows("78:79").EntireRow.Hidden = False
  End If
End If
```

Or a cleaner version, using a `With` block, and using `Worksheets` instead of `Sheets` since sheets can refer to chart objects as well:

```
  With Worksheets("InvPL")
    If IsError(.Range("C59")) Then
      Msgbox "C59 contains an error. If C57=0 then it is a divide by zero error."
    Else
      If .Range("C59").Value = "0" Then
        .Rows("78:79").EntireRow.Hidden = True
      Else
        .Rows("78:79").EntireRow.Hidden = False
      End If
    End If
  End With
```

You can change the logic a bit if you want to hide/un-hide those rows in the case of the error as well.

---

Another option would be to change the formula to return a zero instead of an error when `C57` is `0`:

```
=IF(C57=0,0,ROUNDUP(D59/C57,0))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir! Works brilliantly!